# I'm Getting Bad Request Error After Uploading the Video

Tags: reactjs, django, http, frontend, http-post

I'm using Django and React to make a YouTube clone.

I tried to post the video on the frontend side, and got an error in terminal:

```
<QueryDict: {'title': ['Test Video Creation'], 'user': ['1'], 'description': ['Is it working?'], 'image': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: attachment.png (image/png)>], 'video': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: video-for-fatube.mp4 (video/mp4)>]}>Bad Request: /api/admin/create/
```

And the problem is not in the backend settings, because when I made a post request in the postman, the video was succesfully created. [image: Image where the postman cretaed the video.]

**creat.js** File on frontend side to create videos.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axiosInstance from '../../axios';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
//MaterialUI
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import axios from "axios";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import PhotoCamera from '@material-ui/icons/PhotoCamera';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
}));

export default function Create() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
        title: '',
        description: '',
    });

    const [videoData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);
    const [videoimage, setVideoImage] = useState(null);
    const [videovideo, setVideoVideo] = useState(null);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        if ([e.target.name] == 'image') {
            setVideoImage({
                image: e.target.files,
            });
            console.log(e.target.files);
        }
        if ([e.target.name] == 'video') {
            setVideoVideo({
                video: e.target.files,
            });
            console.log(e.target.files);
        }
        if ([e.target.name] == 'title') {
            updateFormData({
                ...videoData,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
            });
        } else {
            updateFormData({
                ...videoData,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
            });
        }
    };
    

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
        const URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/create/';
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('title', videoData.title);
        formData.append('user', 1);
        formData.append('description', videoData.description);
        formData.append('image', videoimage.image[0]);
        formData.append('video', videovideo.video[0]);
        axios
            .post(URL, formData, config)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
    
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Avatar className={classes.avatar}></Avatar>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Create New Video
                </Typography>
                <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <TextField
                                variant="outlined"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="title"
                                label="Video Title"
                                name="title"
                                autoComplete="title"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <TextField
                                variant="outlined"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="description"
                                label="Video Description"
                                name="description"
                                autoComplete="description"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                multiline
                                rows={4}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <input
                            accept="image/*"
                            className={classes.input}
                            id="video-image"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            name="image"
                            type="file"
                        />
                        <input
                            accept="video/*"
                            className={classes.input}
                            id="video-video"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            name="video"
                            type="file"
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.submit}
                        onClick={handleSubmit}
                    >
                        Create Video
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

If you want to look at the whole project, here is Github: https://github.com/PHILLyaHI/diplom-work

Comment: make sure you have added authorization token in headers in postman

Answer (score 0):

What I did to make it work is I deleted files in the media folder and deleted all the videos.